# How can I quickly amass resources?

Tags: kantai-collection

The next event in Kantai Collection will start when the anime ends, so I want to gather as much resources as I can before it starts to prepare for it.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is 3 ways to collect resources

1/ Automatic regeneration

As long as you are under the softcap, you regenerate your resources at 3 every 3 minutes (except bauxite, which recovers 1 per 3 minutes)

The softcap scales with HQ level and uses the following formula. 250x(HQ level+3)

2/ Expeditions

Expeditions are the best way to collect resources and can be collected till you reach the hardcap of 300.000

the best expeditions to run vary and also depend on your activity (exp 2 has the best ammo/time rate but only lasts 30 minutes)

most expeditions also give multiple resources and all of them require very specific compositions or equips. [check the wiki for detailed descriptions](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Expedition#Theoretical_Hourly_Net_Earnings).

Also, sparkling your fleet gives you a chance (+/- 16% per sparkled ship) of a great success, which increases the resources you get by 50%.

3/ Sorties

Fuel and ammo can be gotten from sorties to world 2-3. The only way to do this with profit is using subs, ideally 2 or 3 (the less the more you profit but the higher the risk for damage). be advised that most subs remodel into aviation subs that are more expensive to run and higher level subs start getting long repair times. This is a hard way for getting extra resources but can outdo expeditions.

Bauxite can be gotten from world 2-2, possibly while farming world 2 bosses for one of the quests. make sure not to use planes or you'll loose more bauxite then you gain.

edit: with recent updates, you could use a seaplane fighter to secure AS with minimal plane losses. Aviation Subs could be ideal for this due to their low slots and the way Rounding works, you usually wont suffer bauxite losses.

Steel is harder or impossible to get this way. 3-2 has a steel node but results in a hard battle afterwards.

4/ quests

If you are careful about how you do (daily/weekly) quests you can run most with a profit. building three ships with minimum resources gives you some extra's. if you do this daily, the resources start piling up.